# Referencing previous rows of a data.frame to compute a new column in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr

I am trying to calculate changes in weight between visits to chicks at different nests. This requires R to look up the nest code in the current row, find the previous time that nest was visited, and subtract the weight at the previous visit from the current visit. For the first visit to each nest, I would like to output the current weight (i.e. as though the weight at the previous, non-existent visit was zero).

My data is of the form:

```
Nest   <- c(a,b,c,d,e,c,b,c)
Weight <- c(2,4,3,3,2,6,8,10)
df <- data.frame(Nest, Weight)
```

So the desired output here would be:

```
Change <- c(2,4,3,3,2,3,4,4)
```

I have achieved the desired output once, by subsetting to a single nest and using a for loop:

```
tmp <- subset(df, Nest == "a")
tmp$change <- tmp$Weight
for(x in 2:(length(tmp$Nest))){
tmp$change[x] <- tmp$Weight[(x)] - tmp$Weight[(x-1)]
}
```

but when I try to fit this into ddply

```
df2 <- ddply(df, "Nest", function(f) {
  f$change <- f$Weight
  for(x in 2:(length(f$Nest))){
    f$change <- f$Weight[(x)] - f$Weight[(x-1)]
  }
})
```

the output gives a blank data.frame (0 obs. of 0 variables).

Am I approaching this the right way but getting the code wrong? Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Nest) %>% mutate(Change = c(Weight[1], diff(Weight)))
```

or with just the base of R

```
transform(df, Change = ave(Weight, Nest, FUN = function(x) c(x[1], diff(x))))
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thanks for such a quick response, solved the problem instantly!

Comment: It calculates `FUN(Weight[Nest == nst])` for each unique `nst` in `Nest` arranging the output in a new column `Change`.

Comment: I've tried to use the code in the second option to apply to a similar problem but it is not working.

This time, I am trying to return a column of mean brood size between the two visits, whereby if there is no change from `x[1]` to `x[2]` then `x[2]` is returned, but if there is a change then then mean of `x[1]` and `x[2]` is returned. I have tried this with `ifelse` and a `for` loop, but to no avail.

    `df <- transform(df, Change = ave(Brood, Nest, FUN = function(x) c(x[1], for(i in 2:length(Nest)){ifelse(x[i]==x[i-1], x[i], (x[i]+x[i-1])/2)})))`

I can't see why this doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data.table solution. With large data sets, this is likely to be faster.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,Change:=c(Weight[1],diff(Weight)),by=Nest]
df
#    Nest Weight Change
# 1:    a      2      2
# 2:    b      4      4
# 3:    c      3      3
# 4:    d      3      3
# 5:    e      2      2
# 6:    c      6      3
# 7:    b      8      4
# 8:    c     10      4
```